# How can I pass an object as a parameter in the google app engine RPC flow?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt-rpc

I'm building a pretty basic app, and one thing I want to do is pass an object as a parameter up through the service -> async -> impl instead of passing up a million separate parameters.

so in async, I do something like this:

```
import shared.Profile;
...
public interface ProfileServiceAsync {
    public void addProfile(Profile inProf, AsyncCallback<Void> async);
```

Now, profile is a class in com. ... .shared and I have the following in my ... .gwt.xml

```
<source path='shared'/>
```

That being said when I try to compile I get this error.

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/D:/projects/eclipse/workspace/.../src/com/.../client/ProfileServiceAsync.java'
         [ERROR] Line 11: No source code is available for type shared.Profile; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: just to be sure...

If Profile.java is in src/com/foo/shared, then your .gwt.xml file is in src/com/foo?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from your import.

This isn't :

```
import shared.Profile;
```

but :

```
import com. ... .shared.Profile;
```